# Stop Flickering in paint method

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

Hey guys I want to stop paint method from re drawing when user scrolls down or up in windows mobile 6.5 CE.Can you suggest me.............with example if possible

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows mobile, but look for a DoubleBuffered property on the form. Set it to True.

Comment: Without seeing your code, there's no way we can make any recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into System.Windows.Forms.Control.SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout()

ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Check it out ;)